# Cannot add non-default icons to tabs - Sencha Touch 2.3.0

Tags: sencha-touch

MyApp is just the "Getting Started" basic app that I'm attempting to edit in a bid to find my way around Sencha.

Now all I'm trying to do is add a mail icon to a tab.  Looking in the touch/resources/themes/pictos folder (which I presume is there to show what is available to me as part of the pictos font) I see the icon I want called mail.

Following the online info I found I have entered this in my resources/sass/app.scss file

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
@include icon('mail');
```

I've recompiled the sass file using compass with no errors

My app/view/main.js file contains

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'App Title'
            },

            html: [
                "Content"
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact Us',
            iconCls: 'mail',

            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Contact Us'
            },

            html: [
                "Content"
            ].join("")
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Sencha was then compiled using sencha cmd 4

Now according to all the documentation I can find that should be it, but the icon doesn't display, I've even tried following along with [this tutorial](http://vimeo.com/66191690) to add custom icons from [icomoon](http://icomoon.io/app/#/select) with the exact same result, no errors when compiling but the icon doesnt display.

I should add it seems that sencha uses css to add the icon (font) via the "after" selector and the "content" property but it doesn't seem to be getting set (inspecting via chrome).

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did the trick

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default'; 
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
@include icon-font('Pictos',
inline-font-files('pictos/pictos-web.woff', woff, 'pictos/pictos-web.ttf', truetype,'pictos/pictos-web.svg', svg));
@include icon('mail');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using icomoon fonts then use
@include icon-font('mail',inline-font-files('pictos/mail.woff',woff,'pictos/mail.ttf',truetype,'pictos/mail.svg',svg);

Then include icon

@inclue icon('mailicon','$',mail);